# Why can't I detach a mirrored device if enough replicas are available?

Tags: linux, zfs

`man zpool` states that `zpool detach`

> Detaches device from a mirror. The operation is refused if there are no other valid replicas of the data.  If device may be re-added to the pool later on then con‐sider the "zpool offline" command instead.

When I want to detach a device from a RAID1 mirror setup `main` (which is set up as follows:

```
$ sudo zpool status
  pool: main
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 822M in 0h1m with 0 errors on Mon Feb 23 08:18:15 2015
config:

    NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    main                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                              ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST3250310AS_6RYBY5VD            ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST3250310AS_6RYBRPJJ            ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1                              ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-SAMSUNG_HD103SI_S1Y5J90Z427433  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST1000DM003-1ER162_S4Y048C4     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

) the detachment of devices fails with

```
$ sudo zpool detach main ata-ST3250310AS_6RYBRPJJ
cannot detach ata-ST3250310AS_6RYBRPJJ: no such device in pool
```

Other sources, e.g. the [official Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gcfhe/index.html) indicate that this should be possible as well. What might be causes for the error?

I'm using ZFS on Linux 0.6.4 on Ubunut 14.10 amd64 with Linux 4.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [known bug in ZFS on Linux](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/580) which seems to have returned as regression in 0.6.4 on Linux 4.0.0. I commented on the linked issue page to reopen it. A workaround is to pass the GUID of the device (retrieved with `zdb`) as argument to `zpool detach` instead of the device name used in the pool (as you'd do following the manpage).